# Making aliases for variables

Tags: math-mode, spacing, macros, punctuation, alias

I'm trying to figure out how best to define an alias. I have some moderately complicated variable names, such as `$p^{i,j}_{t}$`, and having to type them over and over again is a pain. More importantly, if I decide later to change my naming convention, I'd have to go back and search replace in my whole document, which seems ridiculous. I've tried to use this method:

`\newcommand{\varn}{$p^{i,j}_{t}$}`

but this method is not powerful enough. First of all, I cannot use it in Math mode, and would have to define another command

`\newcommand{\mathvarn}{p^{i,j}_{t}}`

which seems redundant.

Second of all, latex doesn't know that it's supposed to insert a whitespace after I use the command in a text environment. If I force a whitespace in the command, I cannot use the command just before punctuation like full stop, or comma.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: It is a math expression, so it should always be written with $-signs, embedding the $ will make the code harder to read. Define it without $'s and use $\varn$.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `\ensuremath`  <sub>Running for cover, egreg will come soon.</sub>

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\varn}{\ensuremath{p^{i,j}_{t}}}

\begin{document}
\varn  \qquad    $\varn$

Here is how \varn{} is used in text again \varn.

\end{document}
```

Fir the second part, you may insert an empty atom `{}` after `\varn` like `\varn{}` when you need a space. This is the usual behaviour. Thre is also `xspace` package, but it may fail some times.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand*{\varn}{\ensuremath{p^{i,j}_{t}}\xspace}
\begin{document}
\varn  \qquad $\varn$

Here is how \varn is used in text again \varn.

\end{document}
```

[image]

As noted by egreg, it won't take much work to write `$\varn$` over `\varn`. It is also more symatec for you identify math code. So better define `\newcommand*{\varn}{p^{i,j}_{t}}` and use `$\varn$`.

Comment: Write 100 times on the blackboard "I'll not mention `\ensuremath` for two months" and send a photo on chat when you're done. Seriously: what's the advantage of `...how \varn is...` over `...how $\varn$ is`? I see none.

Comment: @egreg You remind me of my school days :-) Really here no advantage. I will add it to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I will not downvote, but the two concepts you just used --- `\ensuremath{...}\xspace` --- are of the ugliest things you can ever do in LaTeX, pretty much fighting usage of `~\\~\\` for vertical white-space.

Comment: @tohecz you've come across those as well?

Comment: @daleif you mean across ``~\\~\\``? Well, you don't wanna know what one comes across as a typesetter...

Comment: @tohecz: Does it seem that I am recommending those things? Please note that I have used words like `but` `fail`. I was just addressing just what the OP asked and gave cautions too. :-)

Comment: Well, then it's probably just me thinking that we shouldn't give such answers when we know that what OP asks for is bad. It's like a pramacist that shouldn't sell a drug when the person clearly wants to commit suicide using it ;)

Answer (score 6):

Please, never try to "get rid of the 'additional dollars'." First, you easily mis-interpret your math as text. Second, this then leads to doing things like `\varn=0`, which, in text mode, becomes `$p^{i,j}_{t}$=0`, and this get completely wrong spacing. So, you *should* define

```
\newcommand{\varn}{p^{i,j}_{t}}
```

and then use it as in:

```
We have that $\varn=0$ if and only if the guy $\varn$ is really zero.
```